# Configure constraints at runtime

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Is there the possibility that future versions of the bean validation (JSR 303) specification will allow us to configure (add, modify, delete) constraints dinamically, as Hibernate Validator does?

There is a big need for this feature in a project of mine.

Comment: I didn't understand the down vote. This is a useful thing for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Check out our [contribution page](http://beanvalidation.org/contribute/) to get in touch with the Bean Validation expert group and propose new features.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I proposed this one there.

Answer (score 0):

there is always the possibility :-) but I think nobody can answer this question for sure. Although, you can try to follow JSR 303 team mailing list - see the "getting involved" link at https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303